# Add mail merge field with VBA and set specific font settings

Tags: vba, ms-word

The purpose of this VBA is to find the text "Something" in the document, insert a space after it, add a mail merge field named "address" and then format the inserted field with specific font settings. The adding part works fine but the text does not get formatted.

```
Sub AddMailMergeField()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Set the range after "Something" text
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    rng.Find.Text = "Something"
    rng.Find.Execute
    
    ' Insert a space 
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rng.InsertAfter " "
    
    ' Insert the mail merge field "address"
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add rng, "address"
    
    ' Format the inserted field
    With rng
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 30
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you adding mailmerge fields via VBA instead of using a mailmerge main document with all the fields and required formatting already in-situ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code with this:

Instead `With rng` place this

```
    rng.Expand wdWord
    rng.Select
    With Selection
```